# Cannot find a way to call Async method when Initializing a Xamarin.Forms App

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, uwp, async-await

The async/await threading is driving me crazy here. I have done a lot of research on the possibility to do Async initialization.

Here is the problem. I am trying to make my app load into a specific page according to the current apps status. To determine the status of the app. It includes scanning into the Data folder. In order to use the `Storage API` in UWP. I must create an `async` dependency service in Xamarin Forms.

I am using a singleton pattern with an `AppManager` class here.

**AppManager.cs**

```
public class AppManager{
    public static AppManager Instance = new AppManager();
    public List<Jobs> JobList = new List<Jobs>();

    public async Task InitializeAsync(){
        JobList.AddRange(await DependencyService.Get<IFileService>().GetJobs());
    }

    public bool JobExists(string jobName){
        return JobList.Any(j => j.Name == jobName);
    }
}
```

When the App starts, it will need to load the `JobList` from the Data folder first. Then look into the `JobList` and determine which page to go navigate to.

What I am trying to do currently is calling the code below from the constructor of the `App` class.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
InitializeComponent(); // Default

var appManager = AppManager.Instance;
appManager .InitializeAsync();
if(appManager .JobExists("JobA")){
    MainPage = new PageA();
}else{
    MainPage = new PageB();
}
```

This will always bring me to `PageB` as the list is empty because the initialization is not finished. This is caused by running `async` code in `synchronous` thread.

I have read about multiple ways to make Async constructors in [this blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html). However, they still require me to make an `await` function in the call which is not possible in this case.

I have also tried moving the whole `App()` constructor code into an `async Task` function then call `InitializeAsync().Wait()` in the constructor. However, Xamarin Forms will complain at runtime. As `App` is having `null` reference on `MainPage`.

I would like to know if it is possible to achieve the full initialization using an awaited function without involving bad practices(e.g. async void)? I also have some idea of how to work around for the situation, such as using `SystemIO` instead of `Storage API` will still work for Xamarin Forms UWP. But I would really like to go deep into `async` function instead of just making it work. Thanks.

Comment: It will be logical to move your async stuff to one of the Application life cycle events instead of the constructor. Having such a login in constructor is not the best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Xamarin.Forms expects the `MainPage` to be set as soon as it is initialized. If you use `async` call, you need to wait for it to finish and that will inevitably cause XF to complain about the missing page.

There are three solutions for this problem.

You can **display a temporary "loading page"** on startup. In such case you first set `MainPage` to a page that informs the user that the app is loading:

```
public App()
{
   MainPage = new LoadingPage();
}
```

And you then proceed with the `async` operation in the `OnStart` override:

```
protected override async void OnStart()
{
   var appManager = AppManager.Instance;
   await appManager.InitializeAsync();
   if(appManager .JobExists("JobA"))
   {
      MainPage = new PageA();
   }
   else
   {
      MainPage = new PageB();
   }
}
```

Second option you have is to wire up the async initialization tasks **before Xamarin.Forms** is initialized. For UWP, you could go to the UWP project's `App.xaml.cs` file and put this in the `OnLaunched` method override right before the Xamarin.Forms initialization:

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    ...

    var appManager = AppManager.Instance;
    await appManager.InitializeAsync();
    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);

    ...
}
```

This will just prolong the UWP-based splash screen but when Xamarin.Forms is initialized, the `AppManager` will already be initialized.

Final option you have is described in [this blog post](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-async-task-startup/) by Adam Pedley. It allows you to run the task on UI thread but will block until the task is finished using a [`TaskHelper` library](https://github.com/exrin/Exrin/blob/master/Exrin/Exrin.Framework/Common/ThreadHelper.cs).

```
Exrin.Common.ThreadHelper.Init(SynchronizationContext.Current);
Exrin.Common.ThreadHelper.RunOnUIThread(async () => { await MyMethod(); });
```

This should probably be the last option, because it can be considered a hack, than a proper solution.

Comment: The second option can be done on iOS and Android as well right?